# Calculation Notation using Single Quotes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate and rewrite old code from a former co-worker that was written in MATLAB and convert into Python.  I've never seen the following quote notation used before for the calculation of `c` below and am curious about what it is actually doing.

```
a = [25,30,35];
b = [5,10,15];

c = a'\b'  % result is single value of 0.3455
```

The actual application of this process is used with multi-degree variables but I figured I would break it down into a much simpler function.

Comment: The functional version of the backslash \ I believe is the `mldivide()` function. Here is the documentation for it: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html. I have no experience using it but it solves for `x` in the equation `A*x = B`.

Comment: In this post, it also indicates that this may be a relationship B/A = (A'\B')'. Might be worth looking into for insight into breaking it down into simpler functions. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231488-meaning-of-the-symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no "quotes" notation here.
The last line is just

```
c=ctranspose(a)\ctranspose(b)
```

the sign [`'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) is just the Complex conjugate transpose of a vector or array in matlab...

As for the `\` sign, this is just a short for solving systems of linear equations, as mentioned in the comment.